# Mock Kafka broker for Spring Boot JUnit testing without calling it directly

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, apache-kafka

I have Spring Boot application that implements a REST API. When a payload is delivered to the API, it is evaluated then sent to a couple different kafka topics. On exceptions, data is sent to yet another kafka topic.

I'm finding it challenging to write unit tests for this API, as all functionality involves outputting to kafka brokers that aren't there during testing. I have seen tutorials on using the Embedded Kafka object, but they all involve initializing and calling Kafka directly from the test case.

I have had success in referencing my existing broker from the test cases, but running these tests has external dependencies and produces test data to my live topics. This isn't something I can deploy.

Does anyone have recommendations for providing a mock broker for some topics that are produced to as a result of test cases?

Comment: Do you really need to mock a broker, or mock the consumer and producer and sending messages between them? Otherwise, yes the EmbeddedBroker is what you probably should be using, and doesn't have any external dependencies on an existing cluster

Comment: Well the API is using an Autowired KafkaTemplate to produce to topics, and that is constructed with properties specifying bootstrap servers, etc... I'm not trying to actually call a producer with my tests, but it is an unavoidable effect of this code. I suppose that means I'm looking for a broker. Perhaps I need to look into overriding those kafkaTemplate configurations with environment variables?

Comment: Not too sure about that. You would have to create the consumer/producer configs within the test class since you would not know on which port the embedded broker starts on. Therefore the environment variables couldn't be set ahead of time... I think this might help https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/#testing

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know of my results, thank you! @cricket_007

Comment: Do you know how you resolve it @cricket_007?